# c initializing array from file makes first element -1

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables, file-handling

I'm on ubuntu - codeblocks.
I was stuck in a more complex file reading task, so created the simplest test, and it throwed this weird "error" at me.

I have 2 global variables for the sake of simplicity

```
int a[20];
int row=20;
```

a function to initialize the array from a file

```
void load_file(char* filename) {
int i;
FILE* f;

f=fopen(filename, "r");

for (i=0; i<row; i++)
    fscanf(f, "%d", &a[i]);

fclose(f);
}
```

another function to save the array to (the same) file

```
void save_file(char* filename) {
int i;
FILE* f;

f=fopen(filename, "w");

for (i=0; i<row; i++)
    fprintf(f, "%d", a[i]);

fclose(f);
}
```

and because I really don't know what can be the problem here are the other two functions existing in the program:

```
void print_a() {
int i;
for (i=0; i<row; i++)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
printf("\n");
}

void init_a(int val) {
int i;
for (i=0; i<row; i++)
    a[i]=val;
}
```

and here is the main:

```
int main(){

init_a(2);
print_a();
init_a(5);
save_file("a.txt");
load_file("a.txt");
print_a();


return 0;
}
```

the output of the program is:

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
-1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

So the "error" is that after loading the file, the first element in the array is initialized with -1, while in the file there are only 20 5s.
I really have no clue, thanks for any help.

Comment: How do the contents of a.txt look like? Did you forget a space after %d: save_file() <== fprintf(f, "%d", a[i]);

Comment: `fprintf(f, "%d", a[i]);` --> `fprintf(f, "%d\n", a[i]);`

Comment: You don't have even the minimum error checking. Add that and provide a [mcve] with more details. See [ask] and follow the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `a.txt` looks like this:

```
55555555555555555555
```

so when you try to read it again, it does **not** look like 20 integers. It looks like one very big number which is too big for an integer.

Add a space between each integer when printing to the file. Like this:

```
void save_file(char* filename) {
    int i;
    FILE* f;

    f=fopen(filename, "w");
    // Here you should check that f is valid before proceeding

    for (i=0; i<row; i++)
        fprintf(f, "%d ", a[i]);
              //      ^ notice

    fclose(f);
}
```

Besides that you should always check return values from `fopen` and `fscanf`

Comment: The space in the `scanf()` format string for reading is not critical; all the input conversions except `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n` skip leading white space automatically.  No harm is done, but no good either.  OTOH, ensuring space (or a newline) between values when writing is crucial.

Comment: And always check the return values of important function calls such as `fscanf` and `fopen`. Checking `fscanf` return value would have picked up this issue for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thanks for that info - answer updated.

Comment: @kaylum - true, I added it as a last comment.